# Inserting large amounts of generated test data into postgresql database

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I want to insert a billion rows of floaty data into a postgresql database so that I can test the performance of various postgis functions. My effort below takes ages and seems to be really inefficient and the memory consumption seems to balloon. Can anyone suggest a more better way of doing this - I was thinking it would be better to insert a million rows each insert but I can't work out how to build the object eg: `(a, b), (c, d)` to insert.

Any help gratefully received. Please note I am a bit newbie with SQL so I'm not able to digest hyper optimised solutions that require an advances CS degrees to assimilate :) I'm looking for "good enough".

Ta,

Andrew

```sql
do $$
declare 
   position float := 0;
   measurement float := 0;
   counting integer := 0;
begin
   while position < 100 loop
      INSERT into lat_longs values (counting, postition);
      position := position + 0.0000001;
      counting := counting + 1;
   end loop;
   raise notice 'count: %', counting;
end$$;
```

Comment: Nothing you show here should cause memory usage to balloon.  Do you have constraints or triggers on the table?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Typically using `generate_series()` is faster than using loops in PL/pgSQL.

To generate the "position" value, you can use `random()`

The following will insert 100 million rows with random values for the second column:

```
insert into lat_longs(c1, c2)
select g.id, random() * 100
from generate_series(1,100e6) as g(id);
```

I prefer to insert test data in chunks (e.g. 10 million at a time). That is easier to do, if you let Postgres generate a unique value for the first column, e.g. by defining it as an identify column:

```
create table lat_longs 
(
  c1 bigint generated always as identity,
  c2 float
)

insert into lat_longs(c2)
select random() * 100
from generate_series(1,10e6) as g(id);

insert into lat_longs(c2)
select random() * 100
from generate_series(1,10e6) as g(id);

...
```

If you really need a constant increase for the second column you can do that if you have the identity column:

```
insert into lat_longs(c2)
select g.position
from generate_series(0, 100, 0.0000001) as g(position);
```

Or do it in chunks:

```
insert into lat_longs(c2)
select g.position
from generate_series(0, 10, 0.0000001) as g(position);

insert into lat_longs(c2)
select g.position
from generate_series(10, 20, 0.0000001) as g(position);

...
```